# DB2 index based on substring of field values

Tags: db2, indexing

Is it possible to create an index of a table based on substring of one or more field values in DB2 ?

Answer (score 2):

The docs imply that you can create an index on a "key-expression" rather than just a vanilla column [see key-expression here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.intro/db2z_indexes.htm).

Comment: +1 since you're right but it's not always a good idea. Seriously, if you're going to be treating "subcolumns" as a unit, they should be split into separate columns.